# How to draw detection results from tensorflow-js model using opencv-js and react.js

Tags: reactjs, opencv, tensorflow.js

I don't know the reason why I cannot print results on a canvas element in my application. The code below.
The flow is like this: take the stream from a webcam, run detection using my custom tensorflow model - should give me a bounding box of a specific object class. I cannot make the app to render anything on the canvas. I noticed when I call 'cv.imshow(frame)' (a frame captured from the camera) before I call tensorlow `model.executeAsync()` function I can see the image on the canvas. But if I move `cv.imshow()` below that line there's nothing on the screen. I don't know why. Can anyone suggest any fixes to my code or point what I do wrong?

The app:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react"
import Webcam from "react-webcam"
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
import { loadTensorflowModel } from "./closureInteriorDetection"
import { drawRect } from "./utility"
import cv from "@techstark/opencv-js";

import "./App.css"

const App = () => {
  const webcamRef = useRef(null)
  const canvasRef = useRef(null)

  const [modelLoaded, setModelLoaded] = useState(false)
  const [model, setModel] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    loadTensorflowModel().then((model) => {
      setModelLoaded(true)
      setModel(model)
    })
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(model)
  }, [model])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!modelLoaded) return;

    const detectInterior = async () => {
      if (
        typeof webcamRef.current !== "undefined" &&
        webcamRef.current !== null &&
        webcamRef.current.video.readyState === 4
      ) {
        const video = webcamRef.current.video;
        const videoHeight = webcamRef.current.video.videoHeight;
        const videoWidth = webcamRef.current.video.videoWidth;
        if (!video) return;

        // Set video width
        webcamRef.current.video.width = videoWidth;
        webcamRef.current.video.height = videoHeight;

        // Set canvas height and width
        canvasRef.current.width = videoWidth;
        canvasRef.current.height = videoHeight;

        // opencv catpure frame
        let frame = new cv.Mat(videoHeight, videoWidth, cv.CV_8UC4);
        let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);
        cap.read(frame);

        //----------tensorflow detection-------------------------

        tf.engine().startScope()

        const videoTensor = tf.tidy(() => {
          const tfimg = tf.browser.fromPixels(video)
          const resized = tfimg.resizeBilinear([videoWidth, videoHeight]).toInt();
          const expandedimg = resized.expandDims(0);

          return expandedimg
        })        

        cv.imshow(canvasRef.current, frame)  // when showing the frame here all's fine
        const detection = await model.executeAsync(videoTensor);     
        // cv.imshow(canvasRef.current, frame)  // trying to show the frame here - nothing's happen on the screen (?!?)
        const data = []
        for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
          data.push(detection[i].arraySync())
        }

        tf.engine().endScope() // clean unused tensors
        tf.dispose(videoTensor)
        tf.dispose(detection)
        tf.engine().disposeVariables()        

        return {data: data, frame: frame}
      }
    }

    let handle;
    const nextTick = () => {
      handle = requestAnimationFrame(async () => {
        const detectionResults = await detectInterior()
        let _data, _frame
        if (detectionResults) {
          const {data, frame} = detectionResults;
          _data = data
          _frame = frame
        }
        
        if (_data !== undefined && _frame !==undefined) {
          const boxes = _data[1]
          const classes = _data[2]
          const scores = _data[4]

          const imgWidth = _frame.size[0]
          const imgHeight = _frame.size[1]
          const img = await drawRect(boxes[0], classes[0], scores[0], 0.85, imgWidth, imgHeight, _frame)
          if (img !== undefined) {
            cv.imshow(canvasRef.current, img)
            img.delete()
          }
        }
        nextTick();
      })
    };
    nextTick();
    return () => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(handle);
    };
  }, [model])

  return (
    <>
      <p>{`Model loaded: ${modelLoaded}`}</p>
      <Webcam
        ref={webcamRef}
        className="webcam"
        muted={true}
      />
      <canvas
        id="canvasOutput"
        ref={canvasRef}
        className="canvas"
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Code for loading my model:

```
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";

const MODEL_URL = "model_dir/model.json"

export async function loadTensorflowModel() {
    console.log("loading tensorflow-js model...")
    return await tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL)
}
```

Drawing func:

```
// define a label map
import cv from "@techstark/opencv-js";

const labelMap = {
    1: {name: 'interior'},
    17: {name: 'cat'},
    18: {name: 'dog'},
    19: {name: 'horse'}
}

// Drawing function
export const drawRect = (boxes, classes, scores, threshold, imgWidth, imgHeight, frame) => {
    let src;
    let point1
    let point2;
    let color;
    for (let i=0; i<boxes.length; i++) {
        if (boxes[i] && classes[i] && scores[i] > threshold) {
            const box = boxes[i]
            console.log(box)
            // extract vars
            const [y, x, y1, x1] = box

            const text = classes[i]
            const detectedClass = labelMap[text]["name"]
            console.log('detected class: ' + detectedClass)

            // draw with opencv
            color = new cv.Scalar(0,255,0);
            const newFrame = frame
            point1 = new cv.Point(x * imgWidth, y * imgHeight)
            point2 = new cv.Point(x1 * imgWidth, y1 * imgHeight)
            cv.rectangle(newFrame, point1, point2, color, 3)
            return newFrame
        } 
    }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tensorflowjs-opencvjs-reactjs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@techstark/opencv-js": "^4.5.5-release.1",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^3.18.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "react-webcam": "^7.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: No. The app is now abandoned.